# How to create a SQL Server Database from DBML

Tags: sql-server, database, sql, visual-studio

I have corrupted an entire database and I have no access to it or backups. Is there a way to recreate the structure of it using a .dbml from visual studio project?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. These lines of code would create the entire database structure:

MyDBMLDataContext con = new MyDBMLDataContext();
con.CreateDatabase();